# Rewrite rule with SSL not working

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I want to redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

And if I go to `https://example.com/aboutus`,

it should also redirect to `https://www.example.com/aboutus`.

Currently, I have this in `.htaccess` but it make ssl certificate disappear.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../.force_ssl -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache.